# Woocommerce - Catalogue Add to Cart button - change default quantity for specific category

Tags: wordpress

On the woocommerce shop catalogue page is it possible to have the 'add to cart' button default to six rather than one, but only for a specific category? Selling wine and want it to add 6 bottles at a time, but also selling other items that will be sold individually.

Comment: Do you want it to be a minimum of 6 for this category at all times, or you just want it to default to 6, and the user is still able to change it to less than 6? The latter is easier, but both are possible.

Comment: Just default to 6 and the user can increase or decrease the quantity as they like.

Answer (score 0):

Add this code to `functions.php` in your theme. Keep in mind that if you update your theme, this edit might be lost. So either save it somewhere to add it again or create a child theme and add it there.

```
add_filter("woocommerce_quantity_input_args", function($args, $product){
    if(!is_cart() && has_term("wine-bottles", "product_cat", $product->get_id())) {
        $args['input_value'] = 6;
    }
    return $args;
}, 10, 2);
```

Replace "wine-bottles" with the actual name, slug or ID of your category.

This will make the default quantity value be 6 for all products in the specified category on all pages where they're displayed.

Comment: Thank you for that, unfortunately it not quite what I am after. Your snippet works correctly from the single product page, but not from the Shop Catalogue page using the 'add to cart' button. It is still only adding a single bottle to the cart, the quantity field is saying 6, but it is not actually calculating the sub total. See this screen shot https://www.screencast.com/t/3HVozy9NON

Comment: I've edited the code so that the cart page should now display the correct number of bottles. But the fact that the catalogue page is not displaying 6 by default means that the template might have been overriden by the theme. Check your theme folder for a directory named "woocommerce" and one of the files there should contain the layout with the input field you're looking for. The value would have to be changed there directly. I can tell you what to change, if you locate that file.

Comment: The theme default catalogue page does not show the quantity, it simply has an add to cart button. See the test site here. https://jenniferturner.com.au/turkeyflat/wines/ I was hoping that I could get this button to add 6 bottles at a time, like the single product page now does. Let me know if you need more information.