# Woocommerce Make Products in Category Equivalent to Ten Items

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I'm using Woocommerce to create a request system of sorts for a music archive. I am trying to set up the cart so that there are no more than ten items allowed. I was able to find a solution to this. However, we have single items that actually are a collection of songs, and should therefore max out the cart as ten items. In other words, when one item from the "collections" category is added to the cart, we want that one item to count as 10 items and not allow any other additions to the cart.
I've searched for and tried multiple PHP functions for days and can't seem to find anything that works for this particular problem. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Found the solution in another thread: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59204523/woocommerce-catalogue-add-to-cart-button-change-default-quantity-for-specifi

Answer (score 0):

> should therefore max out the cart...
>
> ...and not allow any other additions to the cart

I don't think I understand that much, but I think you can use the option "Sold Individually" when creating the product. That would limit to one per cart and therefore max it out.
Here:
[image]

Comment: That seemed like the solution to me at first as well, but I need no other products at all to be able to be added to the cart after one item from the "collections" category is added. I currently have a function that will not allow more than ten items in the cart. So, I need each single item in the "collections" category to be equivalent to ten items.

Comment: Without any kind of code, is going to be difficult to help. Can you add the code of your function?